# совместимость версий vue-charts и chartjs

Tags: vue.js, frontend, chart.js

Проект на vue.js 2.x хочу сделать графики, при сборке проекта vue не может найти export default Chart в chart.js

Думаю, о совместимости версий

Answer (score 0):

Недавно обновилась библиотека chart.js до версии 3.0.1, откатите  до старой версии

```
npm uninstall chart.js
npm install chart.js@2.9.4
```